# Getting special characters error on my website when i access my code using local server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, xampp

I have images that when clicked it will show jquery modal that have content that is carousel.

When i run the code directly my code works(e.g `file:///C:/New%20folder/htdocs/IINO/events.html`) but when i access it using my local server it doesn't work(e.g `http://localhost/iino/events.html`) it just show special set of characters.
[Special Character Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT4vB.png)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var parade = ['img/Parade/1.jpg', 'img/Parade/2.jpg', 'img/Parade/3.jpg', 'img/Parade/4.jpg','img/Parade/5.jpg','img/Parade/6.jpg'];
        var Day1AM = ['img/Day1AM/4.jpg', 'img/Day1AM/2.jpg', 'img/Day1AM/3.jpg', 'img/Day1AM/1.jpg', 'img/Day1AM/5.jpg', 'img/Day1AM/6.jpg'];
        var Day1PM = ['img/Day1PM/1.jpg','img/Day1PM/2.jpg','img/Day1PM/3.jpg','img/Day1PM/4.jpg','img/Day1PM/5.jpg','img/Day1PM/6.jpg']
        var Day2C =  ['img/Day2C/1.jpg','img/Day2C/2.jpg','img/Day2C/3.jpg','img/Day2C/4.jpg','img/Day2C/5.jpg','img/Day2C/6.jpg',]
        var Day2Socio = ['img/Day2Socio/1.jpg','img/Day2Socio/2.jpg','img/Day2Socio/3.jpg','img/Day2Socio/4.jpg','img/Day2Socio/5.jpg','img/Day2Socio/6.jpg',]
        var Day2Award = ['img/Day2Award/1.jpg','img/Day2Award/2.jpg','img/Day2Award/3.jpg','img/Day2Award/4.jpg','img/Day2Award/5.jpg','img/Day2Award/6.jpg',]
        var Day3 = ['img/Day3/1.jpg','img/Day3/2.jpg','img/Day3/3.jpg','img/Day3/4.jpg','img/Day3/5.jpg','img/Day3/6.jpg',]

        var id;
        $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
            var i = 0;
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (id == "parade") {
                var imgsrc = parade.slice();
            } else if(id == "Day1AM") {
                var imgsrc = Day1AM.slice();
            }
            else if(id == "Day1PM") {
                var imgsrc = Day1PM.slice();
            }
            else if (id == "Day2C"){
                var imgsrc = Day2C.slice();
            }
            else if (id == "Day2Socio"){
                var imgsrc = Day2Socio.slice();
            }
            else if (id == "Day2Award" ){
                var imgsrc = Day2Award.slice();
            }
            else if (id == "Day3") {
                var imgsrc = Day3.slice();
            }
            $('.modal-body img').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('src', imgsrc[i]);
                i++;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Maybe adding some code would help. That doesn't seem like an error, just outputted "content"

Comment: What do you mean sir? It just display that set of special characters

Comment: Correct, but you're mentioning it as what you're seeing is an error. Seems like you need to encode. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish so it's tough to help.

Comment: I've just updated my question sir

Comment: Are the images in your local server, also try one image with a `/` in front for example `/img/Parade/1.jpg`

Comment: Yes sir tha images are in the server. I've putting / and still it doesn't work